# string format in Scala

Tags: scala

New to Scala and see people are using sign `f` ahead of a string, here is an example I tried which works. Wondering what is the function of sign `f`? Does it need to be combined to use with %s? Tried to search some tutorials but failed. Thanks.

```
object HelloWorld {

   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      var start = "Monday";
      var end = "Friday";
      var palindrome = "Dot saw I was Tod";
      println(f"date >= $start%s and date <= $end%s" + palindrome);
      // output date >= Monday and date <= FridayDot saw I was Tod
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

> The f Interpolator
>
> Prepending f to any string literal allows the creation of simple
>   formatted strings, similar to printf in other languages. When using
>   the f interpolator, all variable references should be followed by a
>   printf-style format string, like %d.

PS. another somewhat related feature is http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/expression-details

Comment: That is not a sufficiently related feature.  The answer is better without any mention of quasiquotes.  `s"$a $b"` is related.

Comment: Isn't interpolation a specific application of "hygienic macros" ?  On one hand the quasiquotes is a very complex topic that can confuse novices. On another hand its existence is to be known for those who want to learn new things and explore.

Comment: As said by @Rex, no knowledge of macro or quasiquote is need to use/define string interpolation.

Comment: that is why I put it in notes rather than answer body and said the feature is 
"somewhat related". You surely don't have to know how it works just to copy textbook examples, but if you would wonder how it could ever work in strongly typed compiled language then it is a route to explore

Comment: Thanks Arioch, vote up. My confusion is, why write `$start` and `%s` together? `$start` should already put the value of variable `start` inside the string? Thanks.

Comment: @RexKerr, thanks and vote up. Which part do you mean is not related? :)

Comment: @RexKerr, which part in my code do you mean "quasiquote"? Thanks.

Comment: @cchantep, which part in my code do you mean "quasiquote"? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa that is the difference between s-prefix ("splicing") and f-prefix("formatted splicing"). The latter lets you specify not only the value itself, but also the format how to print it. Easy example ( dunno if applies to Scala) TDateTime in Delphi. It is double float internally. But when you print it it converts to year-month-day-dayOfWeek-hours-minutes-seconds-milliseconds. Sometimes that is just a bit too much. So specifying format you may say "show the user year and month and hide all the rest"

Comment: @LinMa if you want to learn about quasiquotes maybe you should google about "hygienic macros" in Nemerle language. Scala was catching up to Nemerle and implemented them looking at research and experience done in Nemerle project. So in Scala documentation might be a bit scarce: the conceptual ideas, reasoning and cons and pros were considered something of "common knowledge". Basically it boils down to a simple question - how can compiler language do strong type-checking for magic sequences inside just a string literal.

Comment: So "under the hood" both s- and f-prefixes split your string into pieces and interlace them with traditional but tedious calls to .toString and similar methods. Quaziquotes is the way to tell compiler "what you see there is not exactly what it looks, it meant to be different code instead, take it from me, quaziquote implementation, instead of this raw source part". That is how string splicing (interpolation) is made possible in Scala. It is a very simple but very comfortable special narrow case of quaziquotes.

Comment: Thanks Arioch, vote up. :)

But what will be replaced by `%f` when Scala interpret the string in my example? I ask this since I think Scala treat `%f` as some values?

Comment: I think - i am not quite sure, you can check it in Scala sources, that Scala does not interpret this string, it compiles it. Interpreting would be lazy approach, using `StringFormat.formatted` ( http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/index.html#scala.runtime.StringFormat ) as displayed at http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-string-formatting-java-string-format-method - but I do not think that is actually used: it would be interpretation, so it would destroy main Scala appeal - to be compile-type statically type-checked.

Comment: So I GUESS that Scala changes `%f`  inside f-splicer string into a call to `java.text.NumberFormat.getNumberFormat.format(double,....)` - but that is merely a guess

Comment: Thanks @Arioch'The for the patience to help, mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 3):

See the explanation [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch01s05.html). For people coming from C the `f` interpolator is a `printf` style formatter.  `%` is to denote the type of data and with a `$` you may may refer to a previously defined variable.
The % in not mandatory. Its just that you will get a format that is decided by the compiler at compile time. Bit uyou may want to change the output format sometimes.

So if i take an example ,

```
var start = "Monday";
  var end = "Friday";
  val age = 33
  var palindrome = "Dot saw I was Tod";
  println(f"date >= $start and date <= $end and age<= $age%f" + palindrome);
```

I could omit the %f and i will see a output of 33 as it will inferred as Int. However i could use %f if i wanted to format it as a float. Also if you use a incompatible formatted you will receive a error at compile time.

Comment: Thanks Som, vote up. My confusion is, why write `$start` and `%s` together? `$start` should already put the value of variable `start` inside the string? Thanks.

Comment: Edited answer with explanation. Please accept if satisified.

Comment: BTW, Som, does splicing in Scala providing for re-ordering of variables? I mean when localising applications, phrases in different languages need different order of arguments. When Martin initiated public discussion of splicing few years ago i mentioned it but AFAIR this idea did not appeal to anyone else... Maybe it still was implemented later?.. Of course its compiled nature makes it much more complex than with purely interpreting printf...

Comment: i dont know the details :(  Can you post a separfate question for that ? Someone definitely out there knows about it i am sure

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya, vote up. But what will be replaced by `%f` when Scala interpret the string in my example? I ask this since I think Scala treat `%f` as some values?

Comment: @LinMA - check "Using scalac print options" section at http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-disassemble-decompile-scala-source-code-javap-scalac-jad  and use it over some simple program with a simple f-splicer string

Comment: @Arioch'The, thanks, read through it and helpful. My major confusion is in my example, I think there should be some variable value to replace sign `%s`, but I do not find it in my example. It will be appreciated if you could clarify how `%s` functions in my specific example?

Comment: @LinMa you "variable value" - actually variable *reference* - is "$start" before it and "%s" after that is a formatting standard, it tells Scala that it should print the previous "$start" as string type. And %f would tell to print it as float/double type. See the first link in my answer. First there goes variable or expression after $-sign, then there *follows* formatting specification after %-sign.

Comment: Yes what @Arioch'The said . Just try changing the %s to a different value and see the error that comes up in the IDE. That is a better way to understanding things.